# Click The Collapsible Content to make it collapsed

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I use collapsible widget in my application. I want it's content to collapse when the user click any position in the content.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/leaderdevil/YE9kF/5/) is my JSFiddle, so you can begin from this.

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" id="AccidentDetailsCol">
                    <div data-role="collapsible" class="animateMe" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="a" data-divider-theme="b" data-collapsed="false">
                    <h3>Accident Details</h3>
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">
                            <li>
                                <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">Accident Number: </h2>
                                <label for="text" id="accNumber" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;"></label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">Date: </h2>
                                <label for="text" id="accDate" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;"></label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">Time: </h2>
                                <label for="text" id="accTime" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;"></label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">City:</h2>
                                <label for="text" id="accCity" class="wrap" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;"></label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">Location:</h2>
                                <label for="text" id="accLocate" class="wrap" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;"></label>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div data-role="collapsible" class="animateMe" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="a" data-divider-theme="b">
                    <h3>Assured Details</h3>
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">
                            <li>
                                <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">Car License Plate Number: </h2>
                                <label for="text" id="accAssLicenPlat" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;"></label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">Claim Number:</h2>
                                <label for="text" id="accAssClaimNum" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;"></label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">Claim Status:</h2>
                                <label for="text" id="accAssClaimStat" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;"></label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div data-role="collapsible" class="animateMe" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="a" data-divider-theme="b">
                    <h3>Litigant Details</h3>
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">
                            <li>
                                <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">Name: </h2>
                                <label for="text" id="accLitName" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;"></label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">Telephone: </h2>
                                <label for="text" id="accLitTel" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;"></label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">E-mail: </h2>
                                <label for="text" id="accLitMail" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;"></label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">Driver License Number: </h2>
                                <label for="text" id="accLitDrivLicen" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;"></label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">Car License Number: </h2>
                                <label for="text" id="accLitCarLicenNum" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;"></label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">Car Brand: </h2>
                                <label for="text" id="accLitCarBrand" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;"></label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">Car Color: </h2>
                                <label for="text" id="accLitCarColor" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;"></label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">Has Insurance: </h2>
                                <label for="text" id="accLitHasIns" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;"></label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div id="histLitInsDet">
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">Claim Number:</h2>
                                <label for="text" id="accLitClaimNum" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;"></label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;">Claim Status:</h2>
                                <label for="text" id="accLitClaimStat" style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;"></label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Thank you for all suggestions and solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following JQUERY code.

```
$(".ui-collapsible-content").on("click", function (e) { 
  $(this).siblings(".ui-collapsible-heading").click();
  $(this).slideUp(300);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YE9kF/6/)

Comment: Just wrong position of my mouse when I'm click. I'm so sorry.... Your answer is the best answer!!